# Как можно запретить пользователю спамить отправкой писем

Tags: backend, nestjs, graphql

У меня есть функция, которая создает токен с данными юзера и отправляет его ему на почту, проблема в том, что эту функцию можно вызывать много раз, а нужно ввести ограничение на отправку писем(не чаще чем раз в 120 секунд). Если навесить Throttle на эту мутацию, то даже если письмо не отправится(например, данные были введены неверно), то пользователь не сможет попробовать регистрироваться следующие 120 секунд. Нужно при отправке письма ввести некий счетчик, который разблокирует эту функцию только если дойдет до 120 секунд.

Comment: ну, просто не отправляйте таких писем.

Comment: а вообще, судя по изложенному, вы просто перевернули всё с ног на голову, и теперь пытаетесь как-то удержаться в этом неудобном положении. становитесь на ноги: пусть пользователь отправляет вам письма, подтверждающие владение почтовым ящиком, а не вы ему.

Comment: А чем debounce не подходит?